# Convert images from JPGS to PDFS with the terminal

Tags: terminal, catalina, pdf, graphics

Good morning,

is there a way to convert image formats such as PNG, JPG to PDF using the terminal?

Would appreciate an answer very much.

Comment: To what end? Why not just use one of the myriad graphics converter apps?

Comment: As described above, the extension files like ".jpg" in ".pdf". I don't want to use third-party apps, I find it more relaxed with the terminal and the great thing about the terminal you always know what it's doing